# PHP Error: all fields are required

Tags: php, html, forms

I am new to PHP (took some classes in college but its been a long time) and I keep getting this error when I submit my form Im not sure where the error is coming from and its driving me crazy! The error says: Error: all fields are required. This pops up when all the form fields have been filled out. Thank you to anyone that can help!

Here is my HTML: 
{

```
            <section id="book-appointment" class="book-appointment gray" style="padding-top: 100px">
                <div class="grid-container grid-container-padded shadow radius">
                    <div class="grid-x">
                        <div class="cell small-12">
                            <header class="section-head">
                                <h3 class="section-title text-center ">
                                    Say Hello!
                                </h3><!-- /.section-title -->

                                <div class="section-head-actions text-center">
                                    Reach us for any questions you might have
                                </div><!-- /.section-head-actions -->
                            </header><!-- /.section-head -->
                        </div>
                        <div class="section-body">
                            <form data-abide novalidate>


                                <!-- First Name -->
                                <div class="grid-x grid-margin-x">
                                    <div class="cell small-12 medium-6">
                                        <label><p>First Name</p>
                                            <input type="text" name="firstname" placeholder="First Name" aria-describedby="exampleHelpText" required>

                                        </label>
                                    </div>

                                    <!-- Last Name -->
                                    <div class="cell small-12 medium-6">
                                        <label><p>Last Name</p>
                                            <input type="text" name="lastname" placeholder="Last Name" aria-describedby="exampleHelpText" required>

                                        </label>
                                    </div>

                                    <!-- Email -->
                                    <div class="cell small-12 medium-6">
                                        <label><p>Email</p>
                                            <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email" aria-describedby="exampleHelpText" required>

                                        </label>
                                    </div>


                                    <!-- Organization Name -->
                                    <div class="cell small-12 medium-6">
                                        <label><p>Organization Name</p>
                                            <input type="text" name="orgname" placeholder="Organization" aria-describedby="exampleHelpText" required>

                                        </label>
                                    </div>

                                        <!-- Board Memebers -->
                                    <div class="cell small-12 medium-6">
                                        <label><p>Board Members</p>
                                            <input type="text" name="board" placeholder="Board Memebers" aria-describedby="exampleHelpText" required>

                                        </label>
                                    </div>

                                    <!-- Info -->
                                    <div class="cell small-12 medium-6">
                                        <label><p>Organization Info? </p>
                                            <input type="text" name="info" placeholder="Organization Info" aria-describedby="exampleHelpText" required>

                                        </label>
                                    </div>


                                    <!-- Budget -->
                                    <div class="cell small-12 medium-6">
                                        <label><p>Budget</p>
                                            <input type="text" name="budget" placeholder="Budget" aria-describedby="exampleHelpText" required>

                                        </label>
                                    </div>



                                </div><!-- /.grid-x .grid-margin-x -->

                                <!-- Textarea -->
                                <div class="grid-x grid-margin-x">
                                    <div class="cell">
                                        <label><p>Project Info</p>
                                            <textarea class="textarea" name="field_message" rows="8" placeholder="Project Info" required></textarea>
                                        </label>
                                    </div>
                                </div><!-- /.grid-x -->

                                <!-- Submit Button -->
                                <div class="grid-x">
                                    <fieldset class="cell auto text-center">
                                        <button class="button action-button gradient-f-100" type="submit" value="Submit">Send <i class="fa fa-paper-plane" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
                                    </fieldset>
                                </div>
                            </form>
                        </div>
                    </div>      
                </div>
            </section><!-- /.book-appointment -->
```

}

And here is my PHP:

```
<?php 
$errors = '';
$myemail = 'email@hotmail.com';//
if(empty($_GET['firstname'])  || 
empty($_GET['email']) || 
empty($_GET['field_message']))
{
$errors .= "\n Error: all fields are required";
}

$firstname = $_GET['firstname']; 
$lastname= $_GET ['lastname'];
$email = $_GET['email']; 
$orgname = $_GET['orgname'];
$board = $_GET['board'];
$info = $_GET ['info'];
$budget = $_GET ['budget'];
$field_message = $_GET ['field_message'];


if (!preg_match(
"/^[_a-z0-9-]+(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,3})$/i", 
$email))
{
$errors .= "\n Error: Invalid email address";
}

if( empty($errors))
{
$to = $myemail; 
$email_subject = "Form submission: $firstname $lastname";
$email_body = "You have received a new message. ".
" Here are the details:\n Name: $firstname \n Last Name: $lastname \n Email: 
$email \n Organization Name: $orgname \n Board: $board \n Organization Info: 
$info \n Budget: $budget \n Message \n $field_message"; 

$headers = "From: $myemail\n"; 
$headers .= "Reply-To: $email";

mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers);
//redirect to the 'thank you' page
include ('Location: contact-form-thank-you.html');
} 
?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd"> 
<html>
<head>
<title>Contact form handler</title>
</head>

<body>
<!-- This page is displayed only if there is some error -->
<?php
echo nl2br($errors);
?>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: you have no field named "name" nor, by the looks of things, "message" so are failing at the initial `if(empty....` tests which is where the specific error message occurs

Answer (score 0):

You have some misnamed variables here (should be `$_GET` because your form defaults to that method and there are no form fields named 'name' or 'message'), so your error is coming from this block of code:

```
if(empty($_POST['name'])  || 
    empty($_POST['email']) || 
    empty($_POST['message']))
{
$errors .= "\n Error: all fields are required";
}
```

I strongly suspect you want the following fields:

```
if(empty($_GET['firstname'])  || 
    empty($_GET['email']) || 
    empty($_GET['field_message']))
{
$errors .= "\n Error: all fields are required";
}
```

Your form has no method specified, so it defaults to GET. This means all of your variables will be in the `$_GET` array, not `$_POST`

```
$firstname = $_GET['firstname']; 
$lastname= $_GET ['lastname'];
$email = $_GET['email']; 
$orgname = $_GET['orgname'];
$board = $_GET['board'];
$info = $_GET ['info'];
$budget = $_GET ['budget'];
$field_message = $_GET ['field_message'];
```

You can also simplify the following block of code, instead of using complex and possibly inaccurate regex:

```
if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))
{
$errors .= "\n Error: Invalid email address";
}
```

Comment: so I made the changes you suggested and now im getting these two errors: 
Error: all fields are required
Error: Invalid email address 

I updated my PHP code above..do you see anything wrong with what I have? Thank you so much for helping me.

Answer (score -1):

This is not a php issue you are looking in post data so your form needs to submit data in post.

`<form method="post" data-abide novalidate>`